# Group anagrams Leetcode question (python)

Tags: python, hashmap

I'm looking at this leetcode question [Leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/group-anagrams/). I'm trying to understand the provided solution which is:

```
class Solution:
    def groupAnagrams(strs):
        ans = collections.defaultdict(list)
        for s in strs:
            count = [0] * 26
            for c in s:
                count[ord(c) - ord('a')] += 1
            ans[tuple(count)].append(s)
        return ans.values()
```

I know we are creating a character count tuple as the key and adding the words that match the tuple as values to the map.

The thing that I'm confused about is this line  `ans[tuple(count)].append(s)`. Why isn't it
 `ans[tuple(count)]=s`. Is the append(s) adding values to the map? I thought maps don't have the append() method?

Can anyone clarify this specific line?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ans` is a `defaultdict` that creates a new list if the key is not currently mapped to anything. Thus, `ans[tuple(sorted(s))]` looks up the current value of the sorted tuple in the dictionary (expected to be a list). If there isn't one, it creates a new empty list and associates it with the key. It then appends `s` to that value. Dicts don't have an `append` method, but the value may.

Comment: So, the map's values are of type list, and we're appending the strings to the list, and the key is the tuple?

Comment: Yeah. Though of course Python won't stop you from putting other types into the map.

Comment: Also note that the `count` construct is unnecessary. I see edits changing the described offered solution from a sorted tuple of the characters of the string to the letter count - you can just use `tuple(sorted(s))` as the dict keys. Two words are anagrams if and only if their sorted representations (as a tuple or as a string really) are identical. EG `"eat"` and `"tea"` both have the sorted tuple representation `("a", "e", "t")`. It's not _wrong_ to turn that into a count structure of 1 a, 1 e, 1 t, and 0 of anything else, but it's not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If `ans = collections.defaultdict(list)` confuses you, you could write like this:

```
class Solution:
   # your question does not have `self`  "def groupAnagrams(strs):"
    def groupAnagrams(self,strs):
        # ans = collections.defaultdict(list)
        ans={}
        for s in strs:
            count = [0] * 26
            for c in s:
                count[ord(c) - ord('a')] += 1
            # defaultdict already sets this for us
            if tuple(count) not in ans:
                ans[tuple(count)]=[]            
            ans[tuple(count)].append(s)
        return ans.values()
```